# Get and Read from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have log files where the name of the file is today's date. and I need to get the errors to attributes in these files if they are between the start and stop times currently kept in the variable. how can i achieve this?

```
<ErrorLogs>
  <Logs Hour_Date="9:34/1_6_2021" ID="1">
    <ErrorGUI>checkbox</ErrorGUI>
    <ErrorType>uplink fail</ErrorType>
    <ProgramPage>Failures Page</ProgramPage>
    <ErrorStartTime>9:34:20</ErrorStartTime>
  </Logs>
<ErrorLogs>
```

Comment: I would *start* by parsing the XML file into a list of objects or similar. Personally I tend to like doing that with manually written code rather than XML serialization libraries, but YMMV. Once you've got an object model, you can work out queries without the XML itself being relevant at all. At the moment, we don't know whether you're struggling with the parsing part or the query, which makes it slightly hard to help you.

Comment: I didn't say anything about sql. just c# and xml @WeiChenChen

Comment: @mert I cannot see any comments referring to SQL other than yours... (Was a comment deleted?)

Comment: yes deleted @MatthewWatson

Comment: Are you trying to filter time of day out of each file or a range of dates (or both)?  The xml has both Date and Time properties.  The date in the file is from 2021 and you said in comments "today's date".  I think you meant the date in the filename.  I also assumed that each xml file can have multiple Logs.  It would of been better to have an xml file with more than one log.

Comment: there is a xml file that's name is log_dd_mm_yyyy.xml. ddmmyyyy is today's date so no problem for this. inside this log there are lots of hh:mm entries. and i need to filter them with a dedicated start and finish time. filtering is in hours for this problem not for days @jdweng

Comment: I updated my code to use Time of Day.  Using XML linq is more efficient than XmlSerialization and my code is only parsing errors that are within the timespan specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ErrorLog> errors = new List<ErrorLog>();

            TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0);
            //create a loop to read all files
            List<ErrorLog> results = ErrorLog.GetErrors(FILENAME, startTime, endTime);
            if (results != null)
            {
                errors.AddRange(results);
            }
        }
    }
    public class ErrorLog
    {
        public string errorGui { get; set; }
        public string errorType { get; set; }
        public string programPage { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan errorStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        static string dateFormat = "H:mm/M_d_yyyy";
        static string timeFormat = "h:mm:ss";

        public static List<ErrorLog> GetErrors(string filename, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
        {
            List<ErrorLog> errors = null;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            List<XElement> logs = doc.Descendants("Logs").ToList();

            foreach(XElement log in logs)
            {
                string errorStartTime = (string)log.Element("ErrorStartTime");
                TimeSpan time = DateTime.ParseExact(errorStartTime, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;

                if (time >= start && time <= end)
                {
                    ErrorLog error = new ErrorLog();
                    error.ID = (int)log.Attribute("ID");
                    error.errorGui = (string)log.Element("ErrorGui");
                    error.errorType = (string)log.Element("ErrorType");
                    error.programPage = (string)log.Element("ProgramPage");
                    error.errorStartTime = time;
                    string strDate = (string)log.Attribute("Hour_Date");
                    error.date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    if (errors == null) errors = new List<ErrorLog>();
                    errors.Add(error);

                }    
            }


            return errors;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: TimeSpan time = DateTime.ParseExact causes error +$exception{"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')"}

Comment: I fixed that yesterday.  Are you using latest code?  I changed to DateTime.ParseExact.

Comment: The problem is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  line at the beginning. how can i ignore this ?

Comment: The line should work.  Do you have any spaces before the open angle bracket?  Remove the spaces.  The error should say line 1 and the column of error.  Try : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: If I need to write this list to another XML, how should I go about it? you also answered for that. I need to add this errors under the flights. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73565005/saving-the-values-entered-in-the-textbox-to-the-xml-file/

Comment: I need an example of what final file will look like.  You would need to add another tag to the other post and then in the IF loop above add the "log" to the new tag in other posting.

Comment: I am trying to get this view . https://paste.toolforge.org/view/1b7f1009

Comment: I updated code in other posting since I added code to the Simulator Class.  I assumed you were adding all errors (not just ones filtered by time).  So you can just take the XElement errorLogs and pass to the simulator with the flight ID.  So you can read file like this : XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);  Then get errors logs : XElement errorLogs = doc.Root;  The last statement will convert XDocument to XElement.

Comment: I get error when i define startTime and endTime with DateTime.NowTimeOfDay;. Do you know why?

Comment: Results were null.  Fixed code to handle null results.

Answer (score 2):

As @JonSkeet mentioned you need to deserialize from XML to object classes. Deserialize the XML as `ErrorLogs`.

```cs
[XmlRoot("ErrorLogs")]
public class ErrorLogs
{
    [XmlElement("Logs")]
    public List<Log> Logs { get; set; } 
}

public class Log
{
    [XmlAttribute("Hour_Date")]
    public string HourDate { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorGUI")]
    public string ErrorGUI { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorType")]
    public string ErrorType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ProgramPage")]
    public string ProgramPage { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan ErrorStartTime { get { return TimeSpan.Parse(_ErrorStartTime); } }
    
    [XmlElement("ErrorStartTime")]
    public string _ErrorStartTime { get; set; }
}
```

Next, working with *System.Linq* to filter data by date range.

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ErrorLogs));

ErrorLogs errorLogs = (ErrorLogs)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

TimeSpan startTs = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0); // Your Start Time
TimeSpan endTs = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0); // Your End Time

var result = errorLogs.Logs
    .Where(x => startTs <= x.ErrorStartTime
            && x.ErrorStartTime <= endTs)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nr3DCw)

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot. If I need to write this list to another XML, how should I go about it?

Comment: Work with `XmlWriter` to serialize back to XML as [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RU1wHU).

Comment: Actually, there is an existing xml file and I need to add these logs under to xmls existing root