# Can't parse the XML to insert to dataGridView

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file and its content is as follows. I want to add the information of the flights in this file to the datagridview. The columns I will create in the datagridview are

```
flight_id, flight_description, flight_date, instructor_num, instructor_name, student_num, student_name
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Simulator>
  <Flight ID="1" Description="sunny" Date="2022-09-09">
    <Instructor Num="6">
      <Name>matt</Name>
      <Surname>matt</Surname>
      <Rank>matt</Rank>
    </Instructor>
    <Student Num="66">
      <Name>matt</Name>
      <Surname>matt</Surname>
      <Rank>matt</Rank>
    </Student>
    <Operator Num="666">
      <Name>matt</Name>
      <Surname>matt</Surname>
      <Rank>matt</Rank>
    </Operator>
    <Technician Num="6666">
      <Name>matt</Name>
      <Surname>matt</Surname>
      <Rank>matt</Rank>
    </Technician>
    <ErrorLOGS>
      <Logs Hour_Date="2022-09-09T09:12:00" ID="1">
        <ErrorGUI>checkbox</ErrorGUI>
        <ErrorType>high</ErrorType>
        <ProgramPage>Failures</ProgramPage>
        <ErrorStartTime>PT9H12M23S</ErrorStartTime>
      </Logs>
      <Logs Hour_Date="2022-09-09T09:12:00" ID="1">
        <ErrorGUI>checkbox</ErrorGUI>
        <ErrorType>high</ErrorType>
        <ProgramPage>Page</ProgramPage>
        <ErrorStartTime>PT9H12M23S</ErrorStartTime>
      </Logs>
    </ErrorLOGS>
  </Flight>
  <Flight ID="2" Description="test flight">
    .................like flight1.........
  </Flight>
</Simulator>
```

I tried something like this but failed

```
string inputpath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Data.xml";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(inputpath);
            IEnumerable<string> names = doc.Root.Descendants("Flight").Select(e => e.Attribute("ID") , e.Attribute("Description"), e.Attribute("Date")).Value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my previous posting code.  Added MakeDataTable.  Than you can make the DataSource of dgv the datatable : datagridview1.DataSource = dt.

```
 public class Simulator
    {
        XDocument doc = null;
        public Simulator(string filename)
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
        }
        public Simulator(string id, string description)
        {
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Simulator></Simulator>";
            doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement flight = new XElement("Flight", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("ID", id),
                new XAttribute("Description", description)
            });

            doc.Root.Add(flight);
        }
        public string AddUser(string flightID, string role, string number, string name, string surname, string rank)
        {
            XElement flight = doc.Descendants("Flight").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == flightID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (flight != null)
            {
                XElement user = new XElement(role, new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("Num", number),
                    new XElement("Name", name),
                    new XElement ("Surname", surname),
                    new XElement("Rank", rank)
                });
                flight.Add(user);
                return "GOOD";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Flight ID doesn't exist";
            }
        }
        public string AddFlight(string flightID, string description)
        {
            XElement flight = doc.Descendants("Flight").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == flightID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (flight == null)
            {
                flight = new XElement("Flight", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("ID", flightID),
                    new XAttribute("Description", description)
                });
                doc.Root.Add(flight);
                return "Good";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Flight ID already exists";
            }
        }
        public string AddErrors(string flightID, XElement errorLog)
        {
            XElement flight = doc.Descendants("Flight").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == flightID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (flight == null)
            {
                return "Flight ID doesn't exist";
            }
            else
            {
                flight.Add(errorLog);
                return "GOOD";
            }

        }
        public void WriteXml(string filename)
        {
            doc.Save(filename);
        }
        public DataTable MakeDataTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("flight_id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("flight_description", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("flight_date",typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("instructor_num", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("instructor_name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("student_num", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("student_name", typeof(string));

            foreach (XElement flight in doc.Descendants("Flight"))
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();

                int iD = (int)flight.Attribute("ID");
                row["flight_id"] = iD;
                string description = (string)flight.Attribute("Description");
                row["flight_description"] = description;
                DateTime date = (DateTime)flight.Attribute("Date");
                row["flight_date"] = date;

                XElement xStudent = flight.Element("Student");
                if (xStudent != null)
                {
                    int studentNum = (int)xStudent.Attribute("Num");
                    row["student_num"] = studentNum;
                    string studentName = (string)xStudent.Element("Name");
                    row["student_name"] = studentName;
                }

                XElement xInstructor = flight.Element("Instructor");
                if (xInstructor != null)
                {
                    int instructorNum = (int)xStudent.Attribute("Num");
                    row["instructor_num"] = instructorNum;
                    string instructorName = (string)xStudent.Element("Name");
                    row["student_name"] = instructorName;
                }
            }
            return dt;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Finally, I took the id number of the row I selected in the datagridview and tried to print the errors in the flight with that id to the listbox. I added it as a new solution to this question. where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Should be :  List<XElement> xLogs = flight.Elements("Logs").ToList();  You need to use Elements(plural) to get more than one Element and the results is a list.

Comment: After than, How can i access to list for print it to listBox ?

Comment: Should be Descendants instead of Elements.  Then add using a for loop.

Comment: You mean "List<XElement> xLogs = flight.Descendants("Logs").ToList();" right?  Then in "string ErrorGUI = (string)xLogs.Element("ErrorGUI");" Element gives error. List<XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Element'

Comment: You need a for loop to enumerate through the List<XElement>

Comment: I mean, How can i print them line by line? It would be nice for me to write errorgui,error type one after the other. https://ibb.co/z7c33TM

Comment: What was wrong with answer in other posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606503/get-and-read-from-xml-in-c-sharp

Comment: Is it possible to print the errors in this list according to the flight id selected in the datagridview, using the list<errorlog> structure you wrote?

Comment: The code would be similar to the MakeTable but instead of getting the Flight Info you would get the Error info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create classes for the simulator and deserialize it like this

```
   public Simulator FromXml(string value)
   {
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(value))
        {
           return new XmlSerializer(Simulator).Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }


public partial class Simulator
{
    [JsonProperty("Flight")]
    public Flight Flight { get; set; }
}

public partial class Flight
{
    [JsonProperty("Instructor")]
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Student")]
    public Instructor Student { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Operator")]
    public Instructor Operator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Technician")]
    public Instructor Technician { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ErrorLOGS")]
    public ErrorLogs ErrorLogs { get; set; }
}

public partial class ErrorLogs
{
    [JsonProperty("Logs")]
    public Log[] Logs { get; set; }
}

public partial class Log
{
    [JsonProperty("ErrorGUI")]
    public string ErrorGui { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ErrorType")]
    public string ErrorType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProgramPage")]
    public string ProgramPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ErrorStartTime")]
    public string ErrorStartTime { get; set; }
}

public partial class Instructor
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rank")]
    public string Rank { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: xmlserializer gives error

Comment: Sorry I did not have time to testrun the code. Just wrote it but it should not be a big problem to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void gridFilter_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
            {
                gridFilter.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                string selectedValue = gridFilter.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(inputpath);
                List<XElement> flights = doc.Descendants("Flight").ToList();
                foreach (XElement flight in flights)
                {
                    string idSelect1 = (string)flight.Attribute("ID");
                    if (selectedValue == idSelect1) {
                        XElement xLogs = flight.Element("Logs");
                        if (xLogs != null)
                        {
                            string ErrorGUI = (string)xLogs.Element("ErrorGUI");
                            string ErrorType = (string)xLogs.Element("ErrorType");
                            string ProgramPage = (string)xLogs.Element("ProgramPage");
                            listBox.Items.Add(ErrorGUI);
                            listBox.Items.Add(ErrorType);
                            listBox.Items.Add(ProgramPage);
   
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```